# Summing across columns with match on dates

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe **df1** with columns ID and date (as a string "XYYYYMMDD")

```
ID <- c(101,101,101,102,102)
date <- c("X20170101","X20170103","X20170106","X20170102","X20170104")
df1 <- data.table(ID,date)

ID      date
101 X20170101
101 X20170103
101 X20170106
102 X20170102
102 X20170104
```

and a dataframe **df2** with columns ID and many dates as headers

```
ID <- c(100,101,102,103,104)
X20170101 <- c(1,NA,NA,2,1)
X20170102 <- c(NA,1,1,1,NA)
X20170103<-c(NA,1,NA,2,1)
X20170104 <- c(2,3,NA,2,1)
X20170105 <- c(1,1,NA,1,NA)
X20170106<-c(NA,1,NA,2,1)         
df2=data.table(ID,X20170101,X20170102,X20170103,X20170104,X20170105,X20170106)

ID X20170101 X20170102 X20170103 X20170104 X20170105 X20170106
100         1        NA        NA         2         1        NA
101        NA         1         1         3         1         1
102        NA         1        NA        NA        NA        NA
103         2         1         2         2         1         2
104         1        NA         1         1        NA         1
```

I would like to add a column **count** to **df1** containing the following: For each ID (e.g 101) and date (e.g. X20170101) in **df1**, the sum of the corresponding cells in **df2** between that date (e.g.X20170101) and the consecutive one in **df1** minus one day (e.g. X20170102, not X20170103). That is,  the new df1 should look like this:

```
ID      date  count
101 X20170101     1
101 X20170103     5
101 X20170106     1
102 X20170102     1
102 X20170104    NA
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go!

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>% gather(date,val,-ID) %>%
  full_join(df1 %>% mutate(tag=1)) %>%
  arrange(ID) %>%
  replace_na(list(val=0,tag=0)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(grp=cumsum(tag)) %>%
  group_by(ID,grp) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(val),date=head(date,1)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(count=ifelse(count== 0,NA,count)) %>%
  select(ID,date,count) %>%
  right_join(df1)

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#      ID      date count
#   <dbl>     <chr> <dbl>
# 1   101 X20170101     1
# 2   101 X20170103     5
# 3   101 X20170106     1
# 4   102 X20170102     1
# 5   102 X20170104    NA
```

Comment: moody, thank you for your solution. I only have one issue. Your code is adding a new row for ID=102 and date=X20170101, which is not present in the original df1. Would it be possible to avoid this?

Comment: See the edited answer, note that one of the values is different from what you stated as your expected output, but I believe it may be a mistake on your part, please clarify if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
count <- aggregate(df1$date), by = list(df1$date), FUN = length)
df1 <- merge(df1, count, by = "date", all.x = TRUE)
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: you're not using `df2` and you have a missing parenthesis on second line

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for the heads up